# Custom ordering for std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm trying to make a program that has a `std::priority_queue` of objects. I want the queue to order the objects based on `A::num`.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class A {
  public:
    int num;
    A (int n) {
        this->num = n;
    }
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Deleting an A\n";
    }
};

struct Compare {
  bool operator()(const A* first, const A* second) {
      return first->num < second->num;
  }  
};

int main() {
    std::priority_queue AContainer(A*, std::vector<A*>, Compare);
    
    AContainer.push(new A(4));
    AContainer.push(new A(8));
    AContainer.push(new A(6));
    
    while (AContainer.size() < 0) {
        A* del = AContainer.top();
        delete del;
        del = nullptr;
        AContainer.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler returns an error, however I'm not sure why or where it is referring to, or how to fix it:

```
error: deduced class type 'priority_queue' in function return type
   24 |     std::priority_queue AContainer(A*, std::vector<A*>, Compare);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/queue:64,
                 from /tmp/HvPOYonaOt.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_queue.h:456:11: note: 'template<class _Tp, class _Sequence, class _Compare> class std::priority_queue' declared here
  456 |     class priority_queue
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If you could help me out with this that would be great.

Comment: Raw pointers with manual new/delete should be used very rarely. Anyway the proper syntax of the with the error should be: `std::priority_queue<A*, std::vector<A*>, Compare> AContainer;`.

Comment: The declaration is all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A*, std::vector<A*>, Compare` are types that you need to supply to the template parameters of `std::priority_queue`, not values you supply to a constructor.

```
std::priority_queue<A*, std::vector<A*>, Compare> AContainer;
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/612fbc3b30be9b36)

Comment: I believe you still have to pass the comparator as a parameter, as just the type alone does not suffice.

Comment: Only if comparator is not default constructable.

Comment: or if it is function pointer as it needs to know which function to point to.

Comment: I feel so stupid because that is such a simple solution that I completely missed.

Comment: @MarekR I cannot find that requirement; and I am logically having a tough time imagining a world where the type alone is sufficient.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue see overload (1).

Comment: @sweenish do you make a point of passing instances of `std::vector<T>` and `std::less<T>` to your `std::priority_queue<T>`s?

Comment: So, I don't. But this seems more to rely on goodwill than anything else for a custom comparator. And in the instances where I've used a lambda, the compiler complained if I didn't pass the actual lambda as a parameter. Maybe I'm just overthinking it.

Comment: @MarekR I missed that in my quick skim. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative fix using C++17 [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

```cpp
std::priority_queue AContainer{Compare{}, std::vector<A*>{}};
```

Which is closer to your example.

https://godbolt.org/z/547Tq1EnY

Answer (score 0):

In this line you use invalid syntax for instantiating a templated class:

```
std::priority_queue AContainer(A*, std::vector<A*>, Compare);
```

The proper syntax is:

```
std::priority_queue<A*, std::vector<A*>, Compare> AContainer;
```

---

Having written this, in modern c++ it is recommended to avoid using raw pointers with manual `new`/`delete` whenever possible.
If you can simply store `A` instances this would be the simplest solution.
If you need pointers (e.g. for using polymorphism, which is not shown in your question), you can use smart pointers, e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    int num;
    A(int n) {
        this->num = n;
    }
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Deleting an A\n";
    }
};

struct Compare {
    bool operator()(std::unique_ptr<A> const & first, std::unique_ptr<A> const & second) {
        return first->num < second->num;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<A>, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>, Compare> AContainer;

    AContainer.push(std::make_unique<A>(4));
    AContainer.push(std::make_unique<A>(8));
    AContainer.push(std::make_unique<A>(6));

    while (AContainer.size() > 0) {
        AContainer.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you don't have to `new` or `delete` any object manually.

A side note: I think you have a typo in your `while` condition - `while (AContainer.size() < 0)` should be `while (AContainer.size() > 0)`.